# Outsystems common menu

Tags: outsystems

I am working on outsystems 10.0. I have created a common menu in my app. It should be only visible after the login page. But in my app it is displaying in login screen too. Plz help me in disabling menu in Login screen.

Comment: Can you perhaps post a screenshot of the widget tree, or even better, post your .oml file for us to have a look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of application are you building, and what Template are you using?

If it is a Web App, both Web Application (a.k.a. London) and SilkUI templates do not have the menu in the default Login screen generated (inside the Common flow). Same thing for Mobile Apps (for Tablet and Phone templates).

If you have a menu in your Login screen, then you must have have a custom Template.

Comment: Its a web Application in which limited users can login. I have created 3screens. First is login screens with conditions on who to login. Second is home screen that should come after successfull login. Third is some Data screen with some data. Now i made changes in the menu that is in the common screen with  menus like Homesceen and Data screen.

Comment: The starter module already has a Login screen that you get pushed to automatically when you do not have the role (i.e. are not authenticated or authorised) to access any screen. You should not need to code another, explicit login screen. Having said that, if you really must do it, it is just a matter of deleting the instance of the "Common\Menu" web block from the screens you don't want to have a menu.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the best solution, but you could wrap the menu in an `If` block with the following condition, assuming you have the menu wrapped in the `False` block of the `If`: `GetUserId() = NullIdentifier()`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if in the login page you have the menu or put it in a IF with getuserid()<>nullidentifier() and put the menu in the true part